# TypeORM - using take/limit with leftJoinAndSelect isn't working as expected

Tags: typeorm

I try to get a relational table by QueryBuilder, it works fine til I try to use skip/offset and take/limit. I expect such return:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, // order.id
        "locations": [ ... ] array of locations with same order.id
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "locations": [ ... ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "locations": [ ... ]
    }
]
```

**order.entity.ts**

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
public id!: number;

@OneToMany((type) => Location, (location) => location.order, {
    onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    onUpdate: 'NO ACTION',
})
public locations: Location[];
```

**locations.entity.ts**

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
public id!: number;

@ManyToOne((type) => Order, (order) => order.locations, {
    nullable: false,
    onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    onUpdate: 'NO ACTION',
})
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'order_id' })
  public order: Order = null;
```

**[Query A] I get the desired output with following code:** (but without using skip/take, the output is at top of this question)

```
const orders = getRepository(Order)
    .createQueryBuilder('order')
    .where('order.customer_id = :customer', { customer: user.id })
    .leftJoinAndSelect('order.locations', 'location', 'location.order_id = order.order_id')
    .getMany(); // output count is 35, output count with limit/take of 10 would be 10
```

**[Query B] If I add skip/offset and take/limit**, it would look like this:

```
const orders = getRepository(Order)
    .createQueryBuilder('order')
    .where('order.customer_id = :customer', { customer: user.id })
    .leftJoinAndSelect('order.locations', 'location', 'location.order_id = order.order_id')
    .skip(0)
    .limit(10)
    .getMany(); // output count is 5
```

But here, the output is correct but the length/count is totally wrong. **Query A** finds 35 orders with always 2 locations. If I remove leftJoinAndSelect from **Query A** and add skip and take, then it will find 35 orders as well. But **Query B**, with a limit/take of 10, gives me a output count of 5. It halfs the output! If limit/take is equal 8, the output is a length of 4. It halfs the output! Obviously, getMany does some magic, so I found getRawMany, what doubles the output. Because to each order, there are 2 locations. That's also not what I need. And the structure of this output is also wrong (as you can see below). getManyRaw is okay, but not if I use it with skip/take, because the output would be obviously wrong, because I need all locations to each order. Group By doesn't help here, because then I would have only 1 location by each order.

The output of getRawMany is like

```
[
    {
        "order_id": 1,
        "locations_id": 100
    },
    {
        "order_id": 1,
        "locations_id": 101
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "locations_id": 102
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "locations_id": 103
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "locations_id": 104
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "locations_id": 105
    }
]
```

As I said, using skip/take here, would give me a wrong result. How can I reach my expected output?

Comment: Using `take` instead of `limit` doesn't work? Because `take` is specifically used for cases like these. But don't use `getRawMany` with `take`. In Query B just replace `limit` with `take` and see if it works

Comment: I just noticed it's a very old question lol - not sure why it came to my recommendations. Hope you found the solution :p

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question, basically what you want to achieve is skip and take parent orders regardless of how many child locations it has. Is this correct?

If my understanding is correct, you may use such approach:

```
const orders = getRepository(Order) // use await if it inside async function
        .createQueryBuilder('order')
        .addSelect('@row_number := ' +
                'CASE WHEN @parent_id <> location.order_id ' +
                  'THEN @row_number + 1 ' +
                  'ELSE @row_number END AS rn, ' +
              '@parent_id := location.order_id'
         )
        .where('order.customer_id = :customer', { customer: user.id })
        .leftJoinAndSelect('order.locations', 'location', 'location.order_id = order.order_id')
        .innerJoin('(SELECT @row_number := 0)', 'init_row', '1 = 1')
        .innerJoin('(SELECT @parent_id := 0)', 'init_id', '1 = 1')
        .orderBy('location.order_id')
        .having('rn <= 10')
        .getMany(); // now output should be 10 in case u want to skip use rn > 10 AND rn <= 20 condition
```

Comment: To make it work with nullable relations add extra condition in WHEN clause
`OR location.order_id IS NULL` and replace sorting part to  `.orderBy('ISNULL(location.order_id)')`